# How to verify signature utilizing accessTokenConverter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, signature

I need to verify signature at resource server. I am signing JWT with private key at auth.server and It is signed OK, but I cannot find a way, how to verify it using accessTokenConverter. In my previous project, I did not use JDBC, so I was using jwtTokenStore and It worked without a problem, but I cannot verify that signature with JDBCTokenStore. How to do that? So code at authorization server works, I need to verify it at resource server... .setVerifiedKey(publicKey) should be working, but I need to configure it with JDBCTokenStore...

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

 //   @Autowired
 //   private JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userCustomService;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer
                .jdbc(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userCustomService);
        ;


    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter(){
            @Override
            public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
                if(authentication.getOAuth2Request().getGrantType().equalsIgnoreCase("password")) {
                    final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    additionalInfo.put("organization", "NEJAKA INFORMACE");
                    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken)
                            .setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
                }
                accessToken = super.enhance(accessToken, authentication);
                ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(new HashMap<>());
                return accessToken;
            }
        };

        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory =
                new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("test.jks"), "password".toCharArray());
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("test"));

        return converter;
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')").checkTokenAccess("hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')");
    }

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenServices(tokenServices); }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/documents/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/users/**").authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());

        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverterr() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("public.txt");
        String publicKey = null;
        try {
            publicKey = IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);

        return converter;
    }


}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  //  private String signingKey = "MaYzkSjmkzPC57L";

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userCustomService;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private PasswordEncoder encoder;

    public SecurityConfig(){
        this.encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userCustomService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.
                        STATELESS)
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();

    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

}
```